# Check CheckBox if inputbox has content and viceversa in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to check the checkBox if the inputbox has content , if inputbox don't have any content it should get unchecked.

I want to create two input box for example first name and last name to separate input box and adjacent to that there should be a checkbox , and that check box should get checked if both the input box have content if not then it should remain unchecked if it is not filled.

Answer (score 0):

On your checkbox, `[checked]="inputValue"` where inputValue is a variable bound to your inputBox.